# How to make random integer reroll each time

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner to coding in general and am trying to learn python and so I have been learning how to make a few basic games to figure things out and practice my basics... I have made a game to guess the number that is generate at a random interval of 0-100 and give feedback on if you guessed higher or lower to narrow it into your results. I managed to make the game work and I started trying to add a replayability framework so when you guess correct the game restarts automatically and a new number is generated to guess, however I am not able to make a new number generate. Originally I made the number generate outside the loop and made a loop that seemed effective but the number stayed the same, added it into the loop and it changed with every guess. so I tried adding a secondary def and pointing to it and making the number regenerate there but it doesnt seem to be making a new number still, and if I remove the generation outside of def replay def game no longer sees num as a valid variable. I am unsure how to accomplish this, any advise would be helpful....

```
import random
num = random.randint(0,100)

def Game():
    print("Guess the Number: ")
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess==num:
        print ("CORRECT!!!!!")
        Replay()
    elif guess>num:
        print ("Sorry to high... Try again")
        Game()
    elif guess<num:
        print ("Sorry to low... Try Again")
        Game()

def Replay():
    num = random.randint(0,100)
    Game()

Replay()
```

Comment: Why are you not simply rolling inside `Game`?

Comment: You should be using a `while` loop instead of using recursion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a example of your code written more correctly according to me:**

```
from random import randint


def play():
    replay = 0
    while replay == 0:
        num = randint(0, 100)  # if you want the number to revert every time you make a mistake, leave the line as it is otherwise put this assignment before the loop.
        guess = int(input("Choose a integer number from 0 to 100: "))
        if guess == num:
            print(f"{guess} is mysterious number")
            replay = 1
        elif guess > num:
            print(f"Sorry but {guess} is high, the number was {num}, try again if you want (0=yes, 1=no)")
            replay = int(input())
        elif guess < num:
            print (f"Sorry but {guess} is low, the number was {num}, try again if you want (0=yes, 1=no)") 
            replay = int(input())
            
            
play()
```